# .NET 6 Razor Page Partial tag helper - Model throws 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a pretty simple Partial View:

```
@page
@using IlgQueries.Common.Interfaces;
@model IlgQueries.Common.Interfaces.ProsByArea;

<ul class="pros-list">
    @foreach (ProByGeoAreaData pro in Model.Pros)
    {
        <li>@pro.FullName - @Model.ProCategoryName - <strong>@pro.City</strong> @pro.PostalCode</li>
        <li>@pro.FullName - @Model.ProCategoryName - <strong>@pro.City</strong> @pro.PostalCode</li>
    }
</ul>
```

and I use this partial view in my ***Index.cshtml*** Razor page:

```
<div class="col-12">
    <h2>@Model.ProsByRegion.TotalItems @(Model.ProsByRegion.ProCategoryName) some text @(Model.ProsByRegion.TotalItems != 1 ? "s" : "") some text</h2>
    
    <partial name="Pros/Shared/_ProsList" for="ProsByRegion"/>
</div>
```

But I get `NullReferenceException` in **partial view**:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Here:

```
@foreach (ProByGeoAreaData pro in Model.Pros)
{
   ...code
}
```

I do have a value in my Index page's Model (`Model.ProsByRegion.Pros` is not null).

Here's the Index model:

```
public class IndexModel : IlgPageModelBase
{
    public ProsByArea ProsByRegion { get; private set; } = default!;
}
```

And `ProsByArea`:

```
public record ProsByArea {
  public ProsByArea(string proCategoryName,
   string areaName, uint actualPageNum, uint totalItems, uint totalPages) 
{
    
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(proCategoryName))
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(proCategoryName));

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(areaName))
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(areaName));

    ProCategoryName = proCategoryName;
    AreaName = areaName;
    Pros = new List < ProByGeoAreaData > (30);
    ActualPageNum = actualPageNum;
    TotalItems = totalItems;
    TotalPages = totalPages;
    
  }

  public uint ActualPageNum { get; }
  public string AreaName { get; }

  public string ProCategoryName { get; }

  public IList<ProByGeoAreaData> Pros { get; internal set; }

  public uint TotalItems { get; }
  public uint TotalPages { get; }

}
```

Why am I getting NRE?

### Update

I opened a detailed exception view, and here's the `TargetSite` prop value:

```
{IlgQueries.Common.Interfaces.ProsByArea get_Model()}
```

why `get_Model()` on **my own** model class (actually, record)?

### Update 2

I converted it to ViewComponent - works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> @page
> @using IlgQueries.Common.Interfaces;
> @model IlgQueries.Common.Interfaces.ProsByArea;
>
> <ul class="pros-list">
>     @foreach (ProByGeoAreaData pro in Model.Pros)
>     {
>         <li>@pro.FullName - @Model.ProCategoryName - <strong>@pro.City</strong> @pro.PostalCode</li>
>         <li>@pro.FullName - @Model.ProCategoryName - <strong>@pro.City</strong> @pro.PostalCode</li>
>     }
> </ul>
> ```

The "get_Model()" exception is relates the above code in the partial view, you are mixing the Razor Pages and the partial view, in the partial view, there is no need to add the `@page` directive, try to remove the `@page` directive from the partial view and set the value for the Pros in the Index.cshtml.cs OnGet method. Like this:

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        ProsByRegion = new ProsByArea("C1", "Area A", 12, 10, 5)
        {

            Pros = new List<ProByGeoAreaData>()
            {
                new ProByGeoAreaData(){ ID=101, FullName="F1", City="C1", PostalCode="PC1" },
                new ProByGeoAreaData(){ ID=102, FullName="F2", City="C2", PostalCode="PC2" },

            }
        };
    }
```

And the Partial view like this (change the application and model reference to yours):

```
 @model Core6RazorPage.Data.ProsByArea;

<h2>This is the partial view</h2> 
@if (Model.Pros!=null && Model.Pros.Count > 0)
{
    <ul class="pros-list">
        @foreach (ProByGeoAreaData pro in Model.Pros)
        {
            <li>@pro.FullName - @Model.ProCategoryName - <strong>@pro.City</strong> @pro.PostalCode</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

The result is like this:

[image]